# A wall-outlet's hot-slot pulses energy in only ONE direction...toward the ground. How can this be considered ALTERNATING?

Tags: electricity, electric-current

I'm trying to "see" electrical-energy transfer, at every viewing elevation (from the femto-scopic level to the macro-scopic level), all the way from the power plant (through the application) to the ground.

I can understand how the powerplant's magnet forces energy first in one direction along the main-circuit's wire, then in the opposite direction, 60-cycles-per-second.
But when another wire is connected to that main-circuit (such as a service line to a house), the energy flows in only ONE direction---from the energy-intense wire, through the application, toward the less-energy-intense ground (in accordance with God's design for energy to dissipate equally through the universe.)

*What* at a wall-outlet's hot-slot is alternating? Is it the energy bouncing from one side of the wire to the other as it moves along the wire?

Comment: Why do you say energy only flows towards the ground?

Comment: It's the current that goes back and forth, not the energy.

Comment: I say that energy only flows toward the ground because God designed energy to flow toward equilibrium throughout the universe.  This is what causes energy to desire to leave the energy-concentrated conducting wire along the fastest path toward the energy-dispersed earth.

Comment: The current consists of electrons that move in the same direction that the energy is flowing.  The energy, hopping from electron to electron at the speed of light, causes the electrons to move in the same direction (although much slower).

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing up energy flow and current flow. This is a very common misconception.

People usually think that power plants work by giving you "high energy electrons". Then since energy is a property of the electrons themselves, the flow of energy is the same as the flow of charge. Every aspect of this is totally false.

Here's a better analogy: imagine the power plant is a person rowing a boat. Voltage corresponds with the force the person exerts, and current corresponds with the speed of the oar. The power supplied is $P = VI = \vec{F} \cdot \vec{v}$. Supplying alternating current is rowing back and forth, but you can check that the power supplied is always positive, even while you're rowing backwards -- you are always doing work on the water, and not the other way around.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help my understanding.  However, my understanding still tells me that the application needs energy passing through it in ONE direction---from the source (wall outlet), through the application, toward the ground (in accordance with nature's desire for energy-equilibrium). But  _what_ at a wall-outlet's hot-slot is alternating?  Is it the energy bouncing from one side of the wire to the other as it moves along the wire?

Comment: The energy doesn't "flow to the ground", it flows into the load, where it's transformed into some other kind of energy (like light and heat in the case of a lamp). The energy doesn't flow in the wire, it is associated with the electric field between the hot and neutral conductors.

Comment: But the energy _does_ flow in the wire...from higher-intensity (the power-plant-turbine's pushing magnetism) toward lower-intensity (the ground beyond the application).

Comment: Energy only moves from higher-intensity to lower-intensity, right?

Comment: The ground is also connected to the power plant. You can equally say that the power plant puts energy in the ground and sucks it back through the wire... More normally though you provide two conductors (neutral and live) that provide a closed circuit, and a third (ground) conductor that is there for safety purposes. And there are transformers along the way that further complicate the story. The Poynting vector (flow of energy) is from the power plant into the load; the current is what alternates but since the voltage also alternates their product points in the same direction.